# Exclude a directory when using 'plocate'?

Tags: command-line, locate, updatedb

So after using the locate command on Linux Mint a lot, I ran into the issue of every query returning rows upon rows of results in the /timeshift/ directory - what Linux Mint uses as OS save points.

If I used, say, `locate anaconda activate.sh`, what I might get is:

```
/home/user/.anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts
/conda-activate.sh
/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/activate.d/activate.sh
/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-5.1.5-py39h06a4308_1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-01-09_15-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-01-09_15-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/activate.d/activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-01-09_15-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-01-09_15-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-5.1.5-py39h06a4308_1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-10_04-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-10_04-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/activate.d/activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-14_20-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-14_20-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/activate.d/activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-14_20-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-14_20-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-5.1.5-py39h06a4308_1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-15_21-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/scripts/conda-activate.sh
/timeshift/snapshots/2023-02-15_21-00-01/localhost/home/user/.anaconda3/pkgs/conda-4.12.0-py39h06a4308_0/info/test/tests/test-recipes/activate_deactivate_package/src/etc/conda/activate.d/activate.sh
```

Only the top three results are relevant, so how would one exclude a directory?

Comment: Tried posting this one to StackOverflow already, but it was closed because it's apparently unrelated to "software tools primarily used by programmers" *shrug*

Comment: This is off-topic here too and will also be deleted.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: @Voxel It is a great question and answer; could you perhaps test your question and answer with an Ubuntu VM (where doubtless the results will be the same) and alter these details in your question? I will then undertake to reopen and clear away the comments.

Comment: @Voxel Alternatively, it really should be on-topic on either the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com).  I'd lean towards U&L.

Answer (score 5):

**Manually exclude a directory with grep**

You can use the -v option to get grep to output all the elements that *don't* match the supplied Regex, like so:

```
locate anaconda activate.sh | grep -v "/timeshift/"
```

This will print only paths which don't contain the string `/timeshift/`

---

**Permanently exclude a directory**

Since the issue with the timeshift directory is a frequently re-occuring one, you might want to permanently exclude it from all plocate queries.

As per the `updatedb` documentation, you may add `/timeshift` to `PRUNEPATHS=` in `/etc/updatedb.conf`. Once `updatedb` has been run, all `plocate`queries should now exclude the `/timeshift` directory.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to share your discovery/solution, it would have been useful if on-topic for this site (or placed on SE *Unix & Linux* where it is on-topic)